# The UWP JS app I am making with Visual Studio 2017 will not print numbers generated by JavaScript. Is there a reason or workaround to this?

Tags: javascript, html, uwp

My UWP JS app in Visual Studio 2017 will accept my JavaScript code that is supposed to generate numbers and print in the html field that is provided, but when I test it nothing happens. Is there a reason why this is happening? If so can someone help me find a workaround?
Here is the HTML and JavaScript code:

```js
function displaySuccess() {
  // console.log('yeah');
  displayTask();
}

function displayFailure() {
  // console.log('nope')
}

function displayTask() {
  var a = Math.random() * 25,
    b = Math.random() * 25;
  var c = parseInt(a) * parseInt(b);

  var inputA = document.getElementById("a");
  inputA.setAttribute("value", parseInt(a));
  var inputB = document.getElementById("b");
  inputB.setAttribute("value", parseInt(b));

  var inputC = document.querySelector("useranswer");
  inputC.setAttribute("value", "");
  inputC.onchange = function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    try {
      var result = parseInt(elem.value);
      if (result == c) {
        displaySuccess();
      } else {
        displayFailure();
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  };
}
window.onload = function() {
  displayTask();
}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='a' value={{a}} />
  <input type='hidden' name='b' value={{b}} />
  <input type='hidden' name='calcanswer' value={{calcanswer}} />
  <h3>Solve the multiplication: &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=text name=a size=3 id="a"> x <input type=text name=b size=3 value={{b}}> = <input type='text' name='useranswer' value='{{useranswer}}' size='2' /></h3>
  <input type='submit' value='Answer' />
</form>
```

Comment: displayTask calls displaySuccess, which calls displayTask, which calls displaySuccess, and so on and so forth... and your `displayFailure` does nothing.

Comment: @ceejayoz but its not affecting the code right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. it was my main.js import. apparently since it was in the head rather than inside the body it wouldn't generate.